# I m getting error in getView() in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview and custom adapter....when I run program it will give me error in getview.How can I resolve that error.

code:-

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(m_Context, R.layout.deallisting_card_view, null);
        viewHolder.m_Header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headingText);
        viewHolder.m_Subheader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeaderText);
        viewHolder.m_DummyText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeadingText);
        viewHolder.m_logoImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
        viewHolder.m_getBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getDealBtn);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
}
```

in `covertview = View.inflate(m_Context...);` in this line I am getting error

Comment: call `convertView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.deallisting_card_view, null);`

Comment: can you add the entire class

Comment: post your error log here

Answer (score 1):

this should be done like this.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deallisting_card_view, null);

        viewHolder.m_Header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headingText);
        viewHolder.m_Subheader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeaderText);
        viewHolder.m_DummyText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeadingText);
        viewHolder.m_logoImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
        viewHolder.m_getBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getDealBtn);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder= new ViewHolder();
    vi=convertView;       
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {           
         vi= mInflater.inflate( R.layout.deallisting_card_view, null);
        viewHolder.m_Header = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.headingText);
        viewHolder.m_Subheader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeaderText);
        viewHolder.m_DummyText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subHeadingText);
        viewHolder.m_logoImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appImage);
        viewHolder.m_getBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.getDealBtn);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
}
```

Try above code, hope it will work :)GlbMP